# Bind every line from two variables in a third variable in powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, powershell-2.0

I got two variables, filled with:

```
$Var1:
Dog
Cat
Bird

$Var2:
makes wau
makes miau
makes beep
```

How can I mix both of them like:

```
$Var3 Dog makes wau Cat makes miau Bird makes beep
```

`$Var3 =  $Var1 + $Var2` dosen't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a rapid way (variables's lenght must be equal):

```
$i = 0 ; $var3 = $var1 | % { "$_ $($var2[$i])"; $i++ }
```